# How do I put multiple outputs in several lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, output, mean

I've got an assigment to do and I'd want to automate the process as much as possible.
Basically I have to test how much time does algorithm need to perform merge sort and do so 10 times for 10 seeds, and then for 5 different ranges ((0,600), (0,700), ...).

So far I've managed to make the code spit out all numbers I need, but now I wonder how can I process them (I mean counting mean, max-min value and such) for each run.

Here's the code:

```
import time, random, statistics

myseed = 0
myrange = 600

randomlist = []
random.seed(myseed)

def generate_random_list():
    for i in range(0,myrange):
        randomlist.append(random.randint(0,10000))

generate_random_list()


def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
            
        mid = len(arr)//2
        L = arr[:mid]
        R = arr[mid:]
        mergeSort(L)
        mergeSort(R)

        i = j = k = 0

        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        while i < len(L):
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

arr = randomlist
    
    
def procedure():
    starttime = time.time()
    mergeSort(arr)
    endtime = time.time()
    elapsedtime = endtime - starttime
    
    print(elapsedtime)


while myrange <= 1000:
    print(f"\n this is range {myrange}")
    
    while myseed <= 9:
        print(f"\n this is seed {myseed}")
        
        for x in range(0,10):
            procedure()
        
        myseed += 1
                
    
    myrange += 100
    myseed = 0
```

So far I've thought about putting outputs in several different lists, but how can I do that when I'm using the loop? I'd need it to change the name between iterations, and I have no idea how to do that.

Anyways, all of your ideas are welcome, now I'm getting back to trying to figure it out, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you could collect your results in a dictionary

```
results = {}
def procedure(oi, ii):
    ....
    if not oi in results: results[oi] = {}
    results[oi][ii] = elapsedtime
...
procedure(int(myrange / 100 - 6), myseed)
...
```

resulting dictionary looks something like

```
{
0: {
  0: 0.00019431114196777344, 
  1: 0.0001773834228515625, 
  2: 0.00019407272338867188, 
  3: 0.00017881393432617188, 
  4: 0.00019359588623046875, 
  5: 0.00019812583923339844,
  6: 0.00019693374633789062, 
  7: 0.00019693374633789062, 
  8: 0.00019693374633789062, 
  9: 0.00019598007202148438
}, 
1: {
  0: 0.00019621849060058594, 
  1: 0.00017881393432617188, 
  2: 0.00019693374633789062, 
  3: 0.00019741058349609375, 
  4: 0.00019621849060058594, 
  5: 0.00019407272338867188, 
  6: 0.00019884109497070312, 
  7: 0.0001957416534423828, 
  8: 0.0001938343048095703, 
  9: 0.00019478797912597656
},
...
```

Though if you prefer lists you can use

```
def procedure(oi):
    ...
    if not oi in results: results[oi] = []
    results[oi].append(elapsedtime)
...
procedure(int(myrange / 100 - 6))
...
```

output would be something like

```
{
0: [0.00021266937255859375, 0.0001983642578125, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019621849060058594, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00020694732666015625, 0.000194549560546875, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00020265579223632812, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.00019621849060058594, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.00018024444580078125, 0.0001766681671142578, 0.00019669532775878906, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019669532775878906, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0001983642578125, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019621849060058594, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019311904907226562, 0.00019741058349609375, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00021076202392578125, 0.00027823448181152344, 0.0001773834228515625, 0.0001766681671142578, 0.00017690658569335938, 0.00017786026000976562, 0.00019812583923339844, 0.000194549560546875, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.00019598007202148438, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.00019288063049316406, 0.0001983642578125, 0.00019311904907226562, 0.00019311904907226562, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.0001926422119140625, 0.00019288063049316406, 0.00019812583923339844, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.00019311904907226562, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.000194549560546875, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019884109497070312, 0.00019621849060058594, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0001971721649169922, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.0001983642578125, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.00019407272338867188, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.00019407272338867188, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.00019407272338867188], 
1: [0.00019788742065429688, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.00019669532775878906, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0002193450927734375, 0.00017690658569335938, 0.0001983642578125, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.000194549560546875, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019860267639160156, 0.00019598007202148438, 0.00019598007202148438, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.0002803802490234375, 0.00017690658569335938, 0.0001766681671142578, 0.00017690658569335938, 0.0001761913299560547, 0.00021266937255859375, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.0001971721649169922, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019741058349609375, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.00019669532775878906, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.00019407272338867188, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.0001983642578125, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.000194549560546875, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019741058349609375, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019741058349609375, 0.00019550323486328125, 0.00019407272338867188, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.0001976490020751953, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019478797912597656, 0.000194549560546875, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.00019621849060058594, 0.00019288063049316406, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.0001933574676513672, 0.0001957416534423828, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.00019431114196777344, 0.00019407272338867188, 0.0001964569091796875, 0.00019502639770507812, 0.00019359588623046875, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.00019598007202148438, 0.00019240379333496094, 0.0001952648162841797, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.0001938343048095703, 0.000194549560546875], 
...
}
```

Comment: Hi!
I went with ideas of the previous contributor and managed to pull the project off. But despite that - your solution is really smooth and I already see ways to use it in future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First an observation: your code iterates correctly through different values of myrange and myseed, but it always sorts the same random list as it never creates a new one.

One option for a) fixing this and b) collecting the 10 results for the same (myrange, myseed) parameter combination would be:

```py
while myrange <= 1000:
    print(f"\n this is range {myrange}")
    
    while myseed <= 9:
        print(f"\n this is seed {myseed}")
        
        randomlist = [] # so the random list does not grow all the time
        generate_random_list() # generate a new list for the next 10 measurements
        arr = randomlist # so procedure() calls mergeSort on the right list
        
        elapsed_times = []
        for x in range(0,10):
            elapsed_time = procedure()
            elapsed_times.append(elapsed_time)
        print(f"average: {sum(elapsed_times) / len(elapsed_times)}")
        
        myseed += 1
                
    
    myrange += 100
    myseed = 0
```

You'll notice that this requires that `procedure()` returns the elapsed time like this:

```py
def procedure():
    starttime = time.time()
    mergeSort(arr)
    endtime = time.time()
    elapsedtime = endtime - starttime

    print(elapsedtime)
    return elapsedtime
```

This gets you:

```
...
 this is seed 9
0.0035524999998415296
0.0029768000003969064
0.004242299999987154
0.003511800000069343
0.0029614000000037777
0.003436700000293058
0.004654999999729625
0.009417000000212283
0.005804900000384805
0.0032578999998804647
average: 0.0043816300000798945
```

If you want to calculate the average over different seeds you can use another list in the outer while loop to collect the averages from the inner loop.

The code in the inner while loop is a little awkward because it manipulates the global variables `arr` and `randomlist`. It would be much easier to understand if it passed the random list as a parameter to `procedure()` which could pass it on to `mergeSort()`. (But I didn't want to change too much of your code.)

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for such a detailed help! Indeed, I've forgotten about actually changing seeds between iterations. Well, I didn't, but I haven't implemented it correctly.
Anyhow, I managed to pull the project off, using your tips. You'd make a great teacher, honestly. 
That's all, thank you once again!